# WebSphere JAX-WS inconsistenly throwing validation errors for intentical client requests

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, cxf

When I restart our WebSphere server and send a client request to one of our web services everything works fine. If I try a second time to send the identical request there is a validation error which seems to be related to the namespace of one of the request elements. If I try it a third time it works fine, fourth is a no go, but the fifth works again, and so on..

Every other attempt fails with this error:

```
DefaultValidationEventHandler [ERROR]:  unexpected element (uri:"http://blah.com/ws", local:"clientId"). Expected elements are <{http://blah.com/ws/SERVICE_NAME}user>,<{http://blah.com/ws/SERVICE_NAME}productID>,<{http://blah.com/ws/SERVICE_NAME}USER_IDNT_SCHL>,<{http://blah.com/ws/SERVICE_NAME}instituteNumber>,<{http://blah.com/ws/}clientId>,<{http://blah.com/ws/SERVICE_NAME}VRZ>,<{http://blah.com/ws/SERVICE_NAME}SESSION_INDEX>,<{http://blah.com/ws/SERVICE_NAME}sessionToken>,
 Location: 
[WARNING] Interceptor for {http://blah.com/ws/SERVICE_NAME}SERVICE_NAME#{http://blah.com  /ws/SERVICE_NAME}execute has thrown exception, unwinding now
Unmarshalling-Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://blah.com/ws", local:"clientId"). Expected elements are <{http://blah.com/ws/SERVICE_NAME}user>,<{http://blah.com/ws/SERVICE_NAME}productID>,<{http://blah.com/ws/SERVICE_NAME}USER_IDNT_SCHL>,<{http://blah.com/ws/SERVICE_NAME}instituteNumber>,<{http://blah.com/ws/}clientId>,<{http://blah.com/ws/SERVICE_NAME}VRZ>,<{http://blah.com/ws/SERVICE_NAME}SESSION_INDEX>,<{http://blah.com/ws/SERVICE_NAME}sessionToken>,
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be happening here? I'd appreciate even a suggestion how I should start to debug this. It seems that a successful Request leaves the service in an inconsistent state which is then corrected by the failed Request. At the moment the service itself does nothing except return a hard coded string.

Comment: What WAS version are you using? Following link might help http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM17067

Comment: @AntonNovopashin  I'm using Liberty Profile 8.5.5 As near as I can see I'm not using an \@ResponseWrapper anywhere. Should I be?